# Advanced Custom Fields: Select values and create repeater rows

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a list of posts from a custom post type. What I want to do, is for the user to select (checkboxes) all the posts they want to add and create a repeater row for each selection.

Within the repeater, I am using a Post Object field - this post object field is the same as the checkboxes of custom post type posts. (I am doing this, as I need to pull information from each post and the user can then assign further options to this row)

So, how would I allow the user to select these posts and then upon clicking a button, populate the repeater rows? The select value is the post object value from this repeater...

Any help would be appreciated, as I have spent far too long on this, with no solution in sight!

Comment: Please post the code and possibly screen shots of how your repeater fields are set up. There might be a better way to do this.

Comment: My repeater field is post object (item_post) and quantity (quantity) - basically for each row I want the user to select a post and enter quantity number. The reason for the post object is because I want to have this quantity field x weight (from the custom post type). As there are many posts, I wanted the checkboxes so the user could quickly select all posts and then they can go through the repeater fields to set the quantity for each. Unless there is an easier way?

Comment: As @disinfor says, it would help if we could see screen shots of hoe your ACF fields are set up and the code that displays them.

Comment: Repeater Name = select_posts. Sub Fields = item_post (Post Object) quantity (Number)

Comment: That is *still* not the information we asked for... please edit your question to include the  *full details* of the ACF fields setup (screen shots are fine for this) and your *relevant code*. You need to hep us to help you (Even the answer below has put more effort into their post than you have!). Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [**Question Checklist**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/) to see what is expected of you when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new field group and link it with the post type you require.

In this field group create a field called `posts` and make it a relationship type field, filtered with the post type you want to be selectable to create repeater field rows.

Make sure return format is set to `Post ID`.

[image]

Then create a repeater field called `posts_repeater` with sub rows `post` (post object field) and quantity (number field).

Make sure the `post` (post object field) return format is also set to `Post ID`

[image]

Now add this to your functions. (read my code comments)

```
// run modifications when saving or updating the post
add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post_type', 20);

/**
 * action to run modifications when saving or updating the post
 * @param int $post_id
 * @return void
 */
function acf_save_post_type($post_id) {

    // get our current global post object
    global $post;

    // check we are on the correct post type else return now
    if($post->post_type <> 'post') return;

    // if post post status is publish or draft
    if($post->post_status == 'publish' || $post->post_status == 'draft') {

        // if posts repeater does not already have any rows set
        if (!get_field('posts_repeater', $post_id)) {

            // get the posts relationship field
            $posts = get_field('posts', $post_id);

            // create an empty repeater field array
            $repeater = [];

            // for each post selected in posts relationship field
            foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
                
                // add repeater row and assign current posts field id to post object field
                $repeater[] = [
                    'post' => $value
                ];

            }

            // temp remove the save post action
            remove_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post_type', 20);
            
            // create the repeater field rows
            update_field('posts_repeater', $repeater, $post_id);

            // re add the save post action
            add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post_type', 20);
        
        }

    }

}
```

This will then populate the repeater with the posts selected in the `posts` field when updating the post in the admin.

But if the `posts_repeater` field already has rows, then nothing with happen.

So in your post editor, if you select some posts in the `posts` acf relationship field...

[image]

Then click update, you will now notice the `posts_repeater` field has the select posts from the `posts` field defined in each repeater row. Ready to populate quantities.

[image]

If you update the post again, because the repeater field now has row data, nothing will happen.

User will have to manually add any extra posts via the repeater field.

Comment: Your efforts on Stack Overflow are appreciated, but answering low quality questions is discouraged as it just encourages more low quality questions (This question is just one vote away from being closed)  so you could get downvotes yourself, even for a good answer - see the ["**Answer well-asked questions**" section in "How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Instead, your efforts are better used on answers for people who have put effort into their questions...  If someone is looking for help, they should put in at least as much effort as you have :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten the problem with this question was it was more conceptual for a front end based plugin which doesn't necessarily have code to start with. But i hear ya. Just trying to help the wordpress peeps.

Comment: Those sort of questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow (which is why it has votes to be closed). But also the OP didn't give the additional information that was specifically asked for... I'm all for helping people who are willing to put in the effort and work with us to get to the answer, but if *they* are not willing to put  the effort in, I don't think it's fair that they expect *us* to :)

Comment: @joshmoto appreciate the answer - thank you - rather than a post object to select the posts, I wanted them rendered as checkbox values so the user could simply check each one. However, I can possibly use this code and elaborate on it further. FluffyKitten - appreciate the response and I am sorry for the vague question, but I didn't really have a base to start with

Comment: "*I am sorry for the vague question, but I didn't really have a base to start with*" @PaulVI in that case your question is off topic. Questions should be about one specific coding-related problem, and you're expected to research your issue & make a good attempt at solving it before posting. See [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**Question Checklist**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/). If you still have problems after you give it a go yourself, come back and post a question about the specific issue you're having so we can help.

Comment: @PaulVI use [acf/load_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/) to render `posts` as checkboxes. Just make sure the checkbox value is the id and this will work the same.